# Change logging directory/file for an Upstart service

Tags: logging, service, upstart

I have an upstart service that logs so much that it fills up all space on the hard drive. (This on the default 8GB HDD on an EC2 instance, so it is not a big surprise.) So I would like to change the name of the log file from `/var/log/upstart/XYZ` to `/mnt/log/XYZ`. Is it possible to do so?

I know about the `--logdir` option for Upstart itself, but as I understand, that would simply put everything under `/mnt/log`. I do not mind the other logs staying under `/var/log/upstart/`; I just want to change redirect the output of a single service. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could try just adding ">/mnt/log/XYZ 2>&1". That does not handle the pre-start, post-start, and pre/post-stop sections, but it does handle the main daemon, which is your issue.

Comment: where should I add it?

Comment: At the end of the exec line, so it becomes `exec /path/to/my/daemon --arg1 --arg2 >/mnt/log/XYZ 2>&1`

Comment: I have a similar issue and I have posted the question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/581550/change-logging-directory-file-for-an-upstart-service. It gets difficult to rotate the logs after hack suggested by @CameronNemo.

Comment: This did not work for me. upstart appears to capture output and send it to its own log under /var/log/upstart